# Why don't I have networking connectivity on my virtual machine?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine called vnet208. I used to be able to ssh into it, but I made some changes a while ago and then we had some power outages and now I don't have network connectivity. I can get into the virtual machine on the host. I cannot ping the gateway.

[image: ping]

When I rebooted the machine, I also got the following errors:
[image: reboot errors]

Linux version: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)

Host machine is using Hyper-v

[image: Hyper-v settings]

Result of command `ifdown eth0`/`ifup eth0`
[image]

Result of command `dmesg | grep -i eth`
[image]

```
#lspci -v|grep -i ethernet
00:0a.0 Ethernet Controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DEChip 21140 [FasterNet](rev20)

#dhcpcd eth0
err; eth0; ioctl SIOCGIFHWADDR: NO such device

#/etc/init.d/network start eth0
Interface eth0 is not available
eth0 returned 7 ... failed
```

Note: I am not a server admin, I'm a web developer, but I've been tasked with doing this, so please explain things simply :) If you need additional information, please comment below and I will attempt to get it.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ifconfig -a`?  It seems that your eth0 has either mysteriously disappeared or been renamed.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using a bridge device?  Unless you're doing some weird network stuff you shouldn't need to create a bridge.

Comment: Running ifconfig -a gave me the same output as ifconfig above. It did not show eth0. I don't know why there's a bridge set up, probably from past me trying to get this working, I'm not sure.

Comment: what happen if you perform `ifdown eth0` and then `ifup eth0` ?

Comment: @lese It'll fail since there is no 'eth0'.  What does `dmesg | grep -i eth` show?

Comment: Also, why is there a down vote on this?  Is it not a perfectly legitimate question?

Comment: @DavidKing - I ran those commands and put the results in the question.

Comment: try to find out which devices are available with "ls -la  /sys/class/net/" and add the available device to the bridge...

Comment: Also `lspci -v` will tell you if the system even sees the device and, if so, what kernel module it's trying to use for it.